# Formulas for range of Cells not updating when inserting row with Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to using Macros with Excel, so I apologize if this is a stupid question. 
First off, I'm creating a spreadsheet that will track my week to week expenditures and setting it up so it'll be easy enough to operate on my smart phone. I have three groups of expenses (Food, Fuel, Other), with total and available listed at the end of each group. The groups are organized vertically.

I found a macro that will insert a row above a cell containing specific text and placed it into a button. The issue I have is that it is not updating any of the formulas that sum a range of cells.
For example, if I have a =SUM(B2:B5), then insert a row in that range with a macro, it doesn't update the 'B5' to 'B6'.

Is there something I need to add to the macro to get it to update formulas on the sheet?

Here's the Macro:

```
Dim Col As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long

    Col = "B"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With ActiveSheet
For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
If .Cells(R, Col) = "Food Total:" Then
.Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
End If
Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely occurring because you have the `SUM` formula in B6 and you are inserting a new row at row 6. The `=SUM(B2:B5)` formula never included B6 so it was not automatically adjusting when you inserted the new row.

Create a new blank row between the row containing the `=SUM(B2:B5)` formula and change the formula to `=SUM(B2:B6)` (including the blank row). Now when you insert a new row at row 6, the formula will adjust to `=SUM(B2:B7)`. The blank row will not affect the `SUM` formula outcome and you can change the height and even the backfill to make it look like a bottom border.

Comment: I'm sort of stumped on how to adjust the macro. I wanted to do something where I can adjust 'R' by doing R-1 and dumping it into another variable, but it doesn't seem to work. See my edited post for the macro details

Comment: @Dr.Krieger - yes, that is exactly what it is doing. It located the row containing the `SUM` formula (e.g. *Food Total:*) and inserts a row. You need to insert a blank row above it, include that line in the `SUM` formula and change the insert line to `.Cells(R-1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp`.